# Which Join I need to filter data in SQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am so confused, this is what, I want:

User will send 1 or 2 values (Either Only `tag1` or `tag1` and `tag2`) using `GET method`

This is how my table structure looks like:

> Table Name: "tmdb_movies"

```
tmdb_id        movie_title
1              The Dark Knight
2              Now you see me
3              Logan
```

> Table Name: "tag"

```
tmdb_id        tag
1              Crime
1              Drama
1              Action

2              Crime
2              Comedy

3              Action
```

Now, If the user selects `$tag1` as Crime, And $`tag2` as Action, then "The Dark Knight" movie will echo, because it contains both the tags.

Edit: This is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag

FROM tmdb_movies

JOIN tag ON tag.tag_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id


");
```

Comment: Please show some work...

Comment: I am just asking the join name...Like left join, right join, inner join @SylvainAttoumani

Comment: This is a good guide on JOINS https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ and https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Either INNER join or NATURAL join. There would also be a where condition `WHERE tag IN ('tag1','tag2')` . Also probably a `distinct movie_title` to get each title once.

Comment: @apokryfos I think tag cannot be inside $tag1 or $tag2, because they are variables??, let me try but

Comment: @apokryfos added my code

Comment: use `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag    
FROM tmdb_movies    
JOIN tag ON tag.tag_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id    
WHERE tag IN (:tag1,:tag2)
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id        
");

$stmt->bindParam(":tag1",$tag1); 
$stmt->bindParam(":tag2",$tag2);
```

**Use this if you may have more than 2 tags to search on**

If you have a variable number of tags the user can search on you have to get a bit more crafty. You will need to generate a query with as many parameters (?) as there are tags to search for. Then you can bind via a loop:

```
$searchTags = [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3",...., "tagN" ]; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, tmdb_movies.tmdb_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag    
FROM tmdb_movies    
JOIN tag ON tag.tag_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id    
WHERE tag IN (".implode(",",array_fill(0,count($searchTags)),"?") .") 
GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,tmdb_movies.tmdb_id        
");
foreach ($searchTags as $index => $tag) {
    $stmt->bindValue($index+1,$tag); //bindValue is important.
}
```

Comment: I do not understand, put the code in a order? And their will always be  maximum 2 tags. 

Also i got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' ` in line `WHERE tag IN (".implode(",",array_fill(0,count($searchTags),"?") .") `

Comment: @JohnDoo I sorted it out a bit more . Hope it's clearer

Comment: bro , I think you did not understand my question or something else. 

Nowhere in the code, i can see `$tag1` and `$tag2` How the code will know, the values?

Comment: In your question you mention `$tag1` and `$tag2`. I only just now see the word *category* pop up.

Comment: My mistake,  i wrote category1 instead of tag1....it is $tag1

Answer (score 0):

first just get all tagged data in `CSV` format and after that run this query

```
 SELECT `tmdb_movies`.`movie_title` FROM `tmdb_movies` LEFT JOIN `tag` ON 
`tag`.`tmdb_id` = `tmdb_movies`.`tmdb_id` WHERE `tag`.`tag` IN ($tag1, $tag2)
```